# Is there a way to rotate IP addresses or change proxies in a scrapy script when used as Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to scrape a webpage with Scrapy within a Google Cloud Function and I receive a 403 response.
I tried to scrape other websites in the same way and the script works perfectly as intended, but not on this particular one I'd like to run on. However when I run the script locally from my laptop, it works without a problem. So I conclude that the problem isn't with the script neither is with trying to scrape the website itself, but rather with the fact that I'm trying to run the script from a google cloud function.

I tried using various user agents to imitate that the request is coming from a browser, but that also didn't help, so I ended up deciding I need to somehow use a proxy or rotate ip addresses as GCP or Google Cloud Functions are probably being blocked from that site, but I haven't managed to find a way to do it. Could someone help me out with a code snippet I need to use to adjust my code and solve this please?

I simplified the code that I'm using for the purposes of the question, so in this case I want to scrape a value into the 'text' variable from multiple items on a page, which is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from datetime import date
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

today = date.today()
feed_uri = 'gs://folder_location/scrape_' + today.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '.csv'

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = "testspider"
     start_urls = ["https://thisisthewebsite.com"]

     custom_settings = {
          'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
          'FEED_URI': feed_uri,
          'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36',
     }
     headers = {}
     params = {}

     # For every item with a particular css, yield values under the text variable
     def parse(self, response):
          for item in response.css('the css of the item comes here'):
               yield {
               'text': item.css('the CSS selector of the extractable information goes here').extract_first()
               }

# Entry point of the cloud function
def spider_data(event, context):
     configure_logging()
     runner = CrawlerRunner()

     @defer.inlineCallbacks
     def crawl():
          yield runner.crawl(MySpider)
          reactor.stop()

     crawl()
     reactor.run()
```

Comment: Well… start by getting some proxies you can use. We can't help you with that part.

Comment: That's a fair comment, forgot to say that I have available proxies I can use, but I have trouble figuring out (or finding information about) where and how to insert it in the code in order to run and not throw 403 response. I'm looking for the right syntax.

Comment: https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies